# Centos7 - link up, but no DCHP, unable to bring up next working interface

Tags: networking, dhcp, centos7

I have following configuration: server has two network interfaces, both are attached to switch (and will become `LOWER_UP` after been made up). One of those interfaces will have DHCP server with a lease. Other interface will not provide me with leases.

I need such configuration for CentOS 7, that it will receive IP regardless of interface used for DHCP.

I've tried to make both interfaces `BOOTPROTO="dhcp"`, `ONBOOT="yes"` and `IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"`. But there is a catch: If CentOS detects link on `eno1`, it will continue to try to bring up `eth0`, without trying DHCP on `eth2`. I couldn't disable `eno1`, because by random chance DHCP may be on `eno1` (or `eno2`).

Is here a way to say CentOS "try to bring up all those interfaces"?

Comment: You certainly can't get an IP address from a DHCP server when the Ethernet cable is disconnected! What is really going on here?

Comment: Interface eno1 is connected to switch, but there is no DHCP server on that net in 50% of cases.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I reduced dhcp timeouts to 10 seconds (/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf). It helped. Now eno1 failing fast enough to allow eno2 to find lease before global network timeout happens.